# Debian control files for version strictly less than producing hard-to understand error message

Tags: debian, apt, debian-buster

I am writing a debian package which depends on python3-django.

The control file contains the line:

`Depends: python3-django (>= 1.11), python3-django (<< 2)`

And when I try to install the package, the error message I get is:

`mypackagename: Depends: python3-django (< 2) but 1:1.11.28-1~deb10u1 is to be installed`

To my mind, that version number that is being given for Django should parse as being lower, but for some reason isn't. If someone could advise me what mistake or gotcha I am missing here, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of python3-django you are trying to install is **not** `1.11.28-1~deb10u1` (which would indeed fall within the `[1.11..<< 2)` range), but `1:1.11.28-1~deb10u1`.

The number before the `:` is called the [*epoch*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#version), and it takes precedence over whatever comes after it (that is: it is a number that has a higher precedence than the *major* version number). The default epoch is `0`, and your versioned depends use this default epoch.

So the check is really whether `1:1.11.28-1~deb10u1` is `>= 0:1.11` (which is true) *and* `<< 0:2` which is false and which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: Exemplary answer. Thank you.